# Recursive finding and filling the multiplication of given array value with all previous array values

Tags: c++, recursion

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//hope to get answer using recurssion
void atoA(int a[],int A[],int i,int size){

   if(i<size){
      if(i==0){ A[i]=a[i];}
      else{
         A[i] = a[i]+A[i-1];

      }
      atoA(a,A,i++,size);
   } 
}


int main(){

   int a[]={1,8,4,7,6,2,3,9};

   int size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[1]);

   int A[size],i,j;

   atoA(a,A,0,size);
   /*The answer without recurssion
     for(i=0;i<size;i++){
     if(i==0) A[i]=a[i];
     else A[i] = a[i]*A[i-1];
     }
    */
   for(j = 0;j < size ; j++){
      printf(" %d ",A[j]);  
   }  
}
```

So for array

```
{2,4,3,6}
```

Output should be

```
{2,8,24,144}
```

My iterative version is OK

I tried doing recurrsively modifying and try to print them but could not get the answer it say

```
Segmentation fault : CORE DUMP
```

Can someone point out where i did wrong and what should i modify.Somwhere in calling the function again i feel somewhere it keeps going. I did specify all the constraints but still there seems to be someproblem that persists and i cannot pin point the location.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code.  First, the `i++` is not taking effect before you recurse, thus making your recursion go infinite (it's called with `i` equal to 0 every time).  This is the cause of your segmentation fault (you're blowing the stack).  Use `++i` instead.  The second problem is `A[i] = a[i]+A[i-1];`, which should obviously be `A[i] = a[i]*A[i-1];` if you're trying to multiply numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The recursive call

```
atoA(a,A,i++,size);
```

is not right. Due to the use of the post-increment operator, it is the same as:

```
atoA(a,A,i,size);
i = i + 1;
```

Because of that, you get infinite recursion and stack overflow. Change that line to:

```
atoA(a,A,i+1,size);
```

Also, you have a mismatch between the computations in the two versions.

In the recursive version, you have:

```
     A[i] = a[i]+A[i-1];
```

In the iterative version, you have:

```
else A[i] = a[i]*A[i-1];
```

One of them needs to be changed to see matching results.

Answer (score 0):

I have not work with C++ since my first semesters at the university. Thus you need to tweak and check the following code:

```
boolean mult (int accValue, int pos, int A[])
{
    int value = accValue*A[pos];
    if(pos == 0)
      printnf("[ ");
    else
      printnf(",");
    printf(" %d ", value)
    if(pos = a.lenght()-1)
    {
        printnf("]");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return mult(value, pos++, A);
    }
}

running code

mult(1, 0, A[]);
```

This is a recursive function which will iterate until the trivial case, in this case the condition if(pos = a.lenght()-1) which it will be the last iteration.